# Life of a member variable in IntentService

Tags: android, intentservice

Please explain the life of a member variable in IntentService. Does it get deinitialized when the IntentService gets killed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once an object is no longer referenced, it becomes a candidate to garbage collection, and the same goes to object that are referenced only by this object. This includes the `IntentService` object.